# How can I initialize some rows in a datagrid with a different color?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I want to initialize some of the rows of my **DataGridView** in red, base on a certain condition. The thing is, I've been playing around but I can't get this to work when the **DataGridView** is shown. . I try to do this in the constructor of the **MainForm** but no luck at all.

```
private void UpdateSoldOutProducts ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < productsTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            if ((int)productsTable.Rows [i] ["Quantity"] == 0)
                dataGridViewProducts.Rows [i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;

    }
```

This method is calle in the constructor of the MainForm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can paint DataGridView Rows and Cells using Custom Painting. it is done with 
the [DataGridView.RowPostPaint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowpostpaint.aspx) and [DataGridView.RowPrePaint Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint.aspx).

The another expect is `Paint Event`.

```
private void dataGridViewProducts_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewProducts.Rows)
            {
                int value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Quantity"].Value);
                if (value == 0)
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

You can use *DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs* or *DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs* to set the Row or Cell style on the basis of condition..

You can handle this event alone or in combination with the `RowPrePaint` event to customize the appearance of `rows` in the control. You can `paint` entire rows yourself, or paint specific parts of rows and use the following methods of the `DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs` class to paint other parts:

- DrawFocus
- PaintCells
- PaintCellsBackground
- PaintCellsContent
- PaintHeader

Check this example on MSDN link and try to put you code one of these events.. here you you will get the Currrent row index using the *DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs*

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value);
if (value == 0)                     
dataGridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

**Edit:**
Put you code on Form Load event or DataBinding Completed event. may this solve your problem.

Comment: Well  tried to put my code in the **Form_Load** method but nothing happens. I'll try **Paint** or **PrePaint** event. What I don't understand is that the **Paint** or **PrePaint** event of the **DataGridView** will use the **DefaultCellStyle.BackColor** to paint the color of the cells. So, if I change the value of the property **BackColor** why do I have to handle the **Paint** event myself?

Comment: Brother did you tried **Row**PostPaint , because it works perfectly

Comment: No my friend but I will try that. I didn't try that. Thanks for all your help :))

Comment: Hi Amen, I went ahead and handled the PostPaint event. It works like a charm! Also, its much better I don't have to cycle through out the entire table everytime I update something in the datagrid.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try **RowPostPaint** event, it works for me :

```
private void dataGridViewProducts_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((int)dataGridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Quantity"].Value == 0)
                    dataGridViewProducts.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
```